# Webpack 4 changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I am currently using webpack 4.32 from reactcreateapp and I wanted to rename the format of the output file. Current it using Tilde(~) as a separator in its filename like hits runtime~main.167ad0b7.js.map. Instead of Tilde I want to use dash instead. How can I change that?

I tried googling it and it says I need to adjust

> automaticNameDelimiter: '~'

but unfortunately I think in Webpack 4 they change how you can configure things.  When I search for it can see this but I tried hardcoding it in thedash but it doesnt work and whats with the questionmark beside the property? TIA

```
 interface SplitChunksOptions {
        /** Select chunks for determining shared modules (defaults to \"async\", \"initial\" and \"all\" requires adding these chunks to the HTML) */
        chunks?: "initial" | "async" | "all" | ((chunk: compilation.Chunk) => boolean);
        /** Minimal size for the created chunk */
        minSize?: number;
        /** Maximum size for the created chunk */
        maxSize?: number;
        /** Minimum number of times a module has to be duplicated until it's considered for splitting */
        minChunks?: number;
        /** Maximum number of requests which are accepted for on-demand loading */
        maxAsyncRequests?: number;
        /** Maximum number of initial chunks which are accepted for an entry point */
        maxInitialRequests?: number;
        /** Give chunks created a name (chunks with equal name are merged) */
        name?: boolean | string | ((...args: any[]) => any);
        /** Assign modules to a cache group (modules from different cache groups are tried to keep in separate chunks) */
        cacheGroups?: false | string | ((...args: any[]) => any) | RegExp | { [key: string]: CacheGroupsOptions | false };
        /** Override the default name separator (~) when generating names automatically (name: true)  */
        automaticNameDelimiter?: string;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After ejecting, `config/webpack.config.js`

```
- new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
+ new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),
```

```
- runtimeChunk: true
+ runtimeChunk: {
+   name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`
+ }
```

And have a look at the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) for the `split-chunks-plugin` plugin

```
// after ejecting, config/webpack.config.js:246
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
  name: true, // <--
  automaticNameDelimiter: '---boom---', // <--
},
```

this generates something like

```
build/static/js/vendors---boom---main.b41502e9.chunk.js
build/static/js/vendors---boom---main.b41502e9.chunk.js.map
```

You also could add a function instead of a string to `output.filename` of the webpack config:

```
// after ejecting, config/webpack.config.js:246
filename: isEnvProduction
  ? ({ chunk, ...rest }) => {
    // just for debug
    console.log(JSON.stringify(({chunk, rest}))); 
    return `static/js/${chunk.name.replace('~', '-')}.[contenthash:8].js` 
  }
  : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
```

I think you get the idea, I added some console.log for debugging.

Comment: I found it but I noticed it wasnt the one the was used to create the runtime~main.167ad0b7.js.map. Would you know where to find it?